# Pyro4 for non-network inter-process communication

Tags: python-3.x, pyro

I'm currently using Pyro4 to create daemons that host services which are simply objects that can be called from other daemon-hosted objects or scripts. The objects take quite a long time to initialise and so I need to keep these objects alive rather then simply re-running a script that creates them each time I need to call them.

The implementation is beautifully simple, the client code executes quickly enough for my requirements and it is easy to extend functionality. However, Pyro4 is explicitly made for python programs running over a network and I am just running these daemons internally within a server. There does not seem to be python packages that handle both daemonisation and communication between daemons in the clean way Pyro4 does.

My question: is Pyro4 a right fit for my needs or is there an alternative more standard way of dealing with this use case?

Comment: Just a comment to say I'm glad that you like the implementation with Pyro4 so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many inter-process communication protocols are using "the network" even when running on a single machine. "Network" connections on the local loopback adapter (IPV4 addresses 127.0.0.0/8 and IPV6 ::1) should be particularly fast as this usually doesn't go over a physical network interface at all.

Also, are you aware that Pyro4 also supports communicating over [Unix domain sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)? Those are purely a local system resource.

All in all the phrase "Pyro4 is explicitly made for python programs running over a network" is untrue. I definitely intended Pyro4 to be used between processes even on a single computer. If there's something in particular about Pyro4 that you think is not suitable for this purpose please point it out so it can be improved!

Comment: Just to add to this. I've used Pyro4 for inter-process communication as well and it has worked great. I'm glad to see this posted because I had the same question.